# Will a class variable in python be declared again when a new instance is created?

Tags: python, class, static-variables

I'm practicing the following code:

```
class MITPerson(Person): # a subclass of class Person

    nextIdNum = 0 # identification number

    def __init__(self, name):
        Person.__init__(self, name)
        self.idNum = MITPerson.nextIdNum 
        MITPerson.nextIdNum += 1 

    def getIdNum(self):
        return self.idNum
```

For a reference, here is the superclass:

```
class Person(object):  # superclass

    def __init__(self, name):
        """Create a person"""
        self.name = name
```

I thought that I've already known the answer of this question since I try the following instances:

```
p1 = MITPerson('Mark Guttag')
p2 = MITPerson('Billy Bob Beaver')
p3 = MITPerson('Billy Bob Beaver')
```

Not surprisingly, when I type these into console:

In[12]: p1.getIdNum()

Out[12]: 0

In[13]: p3.getIdNum()

Out[13]: 2

I've read this post and checked all the excellent answers here:
[Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I saw that nextIdNum is assigned to 0 when the first instance p1 is created.
What I feel weird is that why not p2 and p3 also bind nextIdNum to 0 again?
In my imagination, the class variable should be reassigned to 0 once a class MITPerson is created without calling the method.

Did I miss something?

By the way, I've also go through the tutorial here:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

However, I'm afraid it does not give out the answer :(

Comment: A *class variable* is an attribute of the class. It's not going to change unless you change the class object itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I saw that nextIdNum is assigned to 0 when the first instance p1 is created.

This is wrong. `nextIdNum` is assigned to 0 when the class is defined.

Answer (score 2):

A `class` statement is a kind of wrapper around a single call to `type`. The statements in the body are evaluated, then added to a `dict` that is passed to `type`.

Yours is roughly equivalent to

```
def _init_(self, name):
    Person.__init__(self, name)
    self.idNum = MITPerson.nextIdNum
    MITPerson.nextIDNum += 1

def _getIdNum(self):
    return self.idNum

MITPerson = type(
    'MITPerson',
    (Person,),
    {
        '__init__': _init,
        'getIdNum': _getIdNum,
        'nextIdNum': 0
    }
)

del _init, _getIdNum
```

You can see that `nextIdNum` gets initialized to 0 immediately, before any instances of `MITPerson` are created, just like `__init__` and `getIdNum`.

---

When you create an instance, the following steps occur:

1. `MITPerson('Mark Guttag')` resolves to `type.__call__(MITPerson, 'Mark Guttag')`.
2. `__call__` invokes `MITPerson.__new__('Mark Guttag')`, which creates a new instance of `MITPerson`.
3. The new value is passed to `MITPerson.__init__`, at which point the current value of `MITPerson.nextIdNum` is used before incrementing the class variable.
4. Once `__init__` returns, `__new__` returns that value, at which point it is assigned to `p1`.

Notice none of the code in the body of the `class` statement is executed again, although the function `__init__` defined there is.